# dynamically replace a word within javascript function/div

Tags: javascript, html, css

This has me baffled

I have two form inputs, one is text, and one is autoresponder code (javacript or "Raw HTML")

The user clicks a link to go to a javascript function to preview what the result will look like. This is a table  that has a `<textarea>` area on one side, (and so it's easy enough to getElementById and print the message to the box. However, the other is proving more "challenging"

Here is the code.

```
  function preview(per){
if (per == 'sm'){
var txt=document.admin.personal.value;
var bot=document.admin.ad_bot_data.value;
}
else{
var txt=document.admin['personal_'+per].value;
var bot=document.admin['bot_data_'+per].value;
}
    if (txt == ''){
    alert('You have not entered any personal message into responder '+per+'\\nso there is nothing to display\\n\\nPlease corrrect');
    return false;
    }
    if (bot == ''){
    alert('You have not entered any autoresponder code into responder '+per+'\\nso there is nothing to display\\n\\nPlease corrrect');
    return false;
    }
document.getElementById('show_personal').value=txt;
//document.getElementById('preview').innerHTML.replace("%bot%",bot);
document.getElementById('0').style.visibility="visible";
document.getElementById('1').style.visibility="visible";
}   
</script>
</head>

<body onload="HidePop('0');HidePop('1');">
<div style=position:fixed;width:100%;top:20px;text-align:center;pointer-events:none;" id="preview">
<table class="close" cellpadding="8" cellspacing="0" align="center" id="0">
<tr><td colspan="2" align="right"><a href="javascript:void[0];" onclick="HidePop('0');HidePop(1);"><font class="main">CLOSE</font></a></td></tr>
</table>
<table class="choice" cellpadding="8" cellspacing="0" align="center" id="1">
<tr><td colspan="2" valign="top" bgcolor="#ffffff">
<font class="head">Wait ...  before you visit the other site</font><br>
<font class="main">we would like to offer you the chance to subscribe to <i>OUR</i> newsletter.</font>
</td></tr>
<tr><td width="60%">
<font class="main">Here are a few more details:</font>
<br><br>
<center>
<textarea rows="23" cols="45" id="show_personal" class="personal" disabled></textarea>
</center>
</td>
<td>
%bot%
<br><img src="http://www.cristofayre.com/images/my_site/poppa/no.gif" border="0">
</td></tr>
</table>
</body>
</html>
</div>
```

(There are five responders "bot_data_" and five personal message areas "personal_"
for the users, and one set foor me ("sm"). The text message goes in the textarea with "show_personal" are later down the script. The "bot part is either pure HTML, or a javascript code. As such, there's no 'container' I can drop it into. I thought of doing a search and replace using innerHTML, and giving the div container in script a name. You can see it commented out below.

It may be a simple syntax error, or I may need some other code. I await your comments

** Routine called "HidePop" is another function tha uses `"visibility:hidden"` to remove the popup preview

++++++ To Tremor +++++

Here is the code I tried. Any ideas?:

```
document.getElementById('test').value='12345';

<td><p id="test"></p>
<td><div id="test"></div>
<td><span id="test"></span>
```

That showed nothing onscreen. I also tried the following:

```
<td><p id="test">%bot%</p>
<td><div id="test">%bot%</div>
<td><span id="test">%bot%</span>

var t=document.getElementById['test'].value;
alert(t);
```

and that comes back `undefined`

Comment: I don't know why someone would -1 your question, seems like a good question for stack to me. Inside your table cell where you want to dynamically put text, place a div, span or p element with an ID. Create a function to read the contents of that, parse it with regex and re-write the altered html.

Comment: Much of your HTML has been deprecated for 14 years (HTML 4.0.1). Most of the rest of it is unsupported in HTML5. You might want to check that out before pressing on?

Comment: To Tremor: I tried , span and p, gave them an id then tried to write the value in situ but didn't work. (See my edited post above).

Comment: I tried it with <textarea> and it displays the TEXT in the box ... but it won't work with anything else. I even tried to read the whole <div> (id=preview) into javascript to see if I could change that ... and even that came back 'undefined'

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to "Tremor" who pointed me in the right direction with this one. Where I put %bot% in the code above, and then tried to replace it, what I should have done was placed a pair of <div></div> tags here.

I was also "half right" in that it needed to use "innerHTML" in some form. What I should have done is rather than try to set the element with a 'value', (which works with textarea and input types) I should have asked it to place the innerHTML directly.

Here is revised code:

```
//document.getElementById('preview').innerHTML.replace("%bot%",bot);
should actually have been
document.getElementById('bot_data').innerHTML=bot;

and the section in table, should have been:
%bot% (incorrect)
<td><div id="bot_data"></div>
<br><img src ...
```

Glad that's sorted.

In answer to "Andrew", I heed your point about being outdated code, but as I've written about twenty-five PERL/HTML scripts using this outdated HTML - around 2.5GB in all - I'm hoping HTML5 will not replace HTML x overnight, and that the code will be useable for a few years yet. I don't fancy re-coding that little lot!! (NB: I will check out HTML5 to see the major changes)